# Make a bot react to a message above it

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I need a bot to react to a message above the user who sent the command. Right now the bot only reacts to the user who sent the command.

```js
client.on('message', (msg) => {
 if (msg.content === 'Boo Hoo') {
  const reactionEmoji = msg.guild.emojis.cache.find(
   (emoji) => emoji.name === 'BooHoo'
  );
  msg.react(reactionEmoji);
 }
});
```

how would I modify/rewrite this code to make it react to a message above the user who sent the command? I'm thinking it might have something to do with MessageManager, and fetching messages but I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, use the [`.fetch()` method](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch):

```js
message.channel.messages
 .fetch({ limit: 2 }) // get the two latest messages in that channel (cmd and the one aaobve it)
 .then((messages) => messages.last().react(reactEmoji)); // get last (second) entry and react to it
```

Comment: I got so swallowed by the discord.js library that I forgot basic js and didn't think to make a basic array. Thank you for your help :)